# Slider is not autoplay in oshine theme on wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Use oshine theme in WordPress. I create 4 portfolios for homepage-slider and create homepage using portfolio template using horizontal carousel slider but this slider is not autoplay. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which carousel are you using something like an owl or other?

Comment: @Bhardwaj use theme slider not custom slider jquery. Below link use theme http://oshinewptheme.com/v2/

Answer (score 0):

**First** of your theme is paid and I hope there should be an option from admin end to work slider autoplay on or off. like there scroll on the mouse.

**2nd thing:** if there are not any options then you can use the slider id and define the javascript/jquery function like this:-

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var slider = $('.yourslider');

    slider.yourslider({
    autoplay:true,
    loop:true

});
});   
</script> (in footer.php)
```

**3rd:** go to theme directory and find the jquery library file and find the function `autoplay:false,` and make it `autoplay:true,`

The theme is not free that's why I cannot provide you exact solution.

Hope you will get the solution.

Comment: @Bhardwaj Thanks so much. I use paid theme but i can't seen autoplay options in oshine theme.

Comment: Then try 2nd and 3rd options.